# If condition for date in mysql query with more tables

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have three tables from whom i want to show data.Here is example of one table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dateadded` datetime NOT NULL,
`dateupdated` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_by` int(44) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=924 ;)
```

Here created_by is foreign key of users table.I want to get result like this

```
User     TableName    ActionType    Date

XYZ       sales        Inserted        2013-04-23 00:00:00
XYZ       sales        updated         2013-05-23 00:00:00
```

If dateupdated is later than dateadded show updated else show Inserted.
As this is from sales table so tableName is sales
Similarly for all three tables,how this can be done?

User table looks like this

```
Id  User_Name
 1    XYZ
```

Sales table has this data

```
1    2013-04-23 00:00:00    2013-04-23 00:00:00    1
2    2013-04-23 00:00:00    2013-05-23 00:00:00    1
```

Comment: Your show results with columns like `Tablename`, `User`, and `ActionType`.  You show a table that has none of these columns.  Can you explain the relationship between the table and the results you want?

Comment: please check now,i updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.user, 'sales', 
case
    when s.dateadded = s.dateupdated
    then 'Inserted'
    else 'Updated'
end,
case
    when s.dateadded = s.dateupdated
    then s.dateadded
    else s.dateupdated
end
FROM users u
JOIN sales s
ON u.id = s.created_by
```

The query I've written shoud resolve your request, but I advice you to think again your model.

I think your sales table as rows for each movement, every movement has got a typization (Inserted, Updated and so on), the date are unique for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
SELECT GREATEST(dateupdated, dateadded)
```

You can specify as many columns as you want, so you can do this for all tables simultaneously too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name, 'sales',
      IF(dateadded>=dateupdated,'Inserted','Updated'),
      GREATEST(dateadded,dateupdated)
FROM users,sales
WHERE users.id = created_by
```